# Convert image to button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using Blend for visual Studio 2012 and I have a problem, I need to change the image from a resource to three buttons

I convert an image to button

these resource is for one button:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="AppBtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Image x:Name="image" Source="1394235016_close.png" Stretch="None" Opacity="0.8" />
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="image" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Style="{DynamicResource AppBtn}" Click="Button_Click" Margin="2,0,2,0" />
```

for one button is ok but I need to aply this resource to another two button but I need to change the image tag (for change the image)

how I do this?

Comment: What are you meaning by Tag, when you say that I think of the Tag property.

Comment: this:  <Image x:Name="image" Source="1394235016_close.png" Stretch="None" Opacity="0.8" /> with this I aply the same image for my other two buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and it worked

in your style do the following

```
  <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                    Path=Tag}" Stretch="None" Opacity="0.8" />
```

and in your button

```
 <Button x:Name="Search_Button" Click="Button_Click"
           Style="{DynamicResource AppBtn}" Tag="your resource"/>
```

Change the tag in each button to give your image resource

Comment: thanks man.. it's works! .. the buttons are not visible in the design but yes in execution :/ ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this
In the style template

```
 <Image x:Name="image" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" Stretch="None" Opacity="0.8" />
```

and when you apply the button on page try following;

```
 <local:AppBtn ImageSource="*yoursource*" />
 <Button Style="{DynamicResource AppBtn}" Click="Button_Click" Margin="2,0,2,0" />
```

repeat for each button with different image source

Not sure it will work, but you can try

Comment: mm not works.. ImageSource is not accessible or recognize,, and local:AppBtn is not supported in a wpf applicaation